# Why does error handler not handle a second error?

Tags: excel, vba, error-handling

I am trying to copy a given sheet and rename that copy sheet2, but if sheet2 exists rename it sheet3, and if sheet3 exists rename it sheet4 etc.

I am trying to use an infinite while loop with error handling (i.e. if it tries to rename the sheet and an identical sheet exists, it handles the error and increases the suffix by 1, but if no error occurs, it exits the loop).

```
Sub Clone()

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    Dim ParamsToBeCloned As String
    Dim wsNumber As Long
    Dim suffix As Long

    ParamsToBeCloned = Sheets("Interface").Range("ParamsToBeCloned")

    wsNumber = Sheets(ParamsToBeCloned).index
    Sheets(ParamsToBeCloned).Copy after:=Sheets(wsNumber)

    suffix = 2
    Do While True
        On Error GoTo sheetExists
        ActiveSheet.Name = ParamsToBeCloned & suffix
        Exit Do
sheetExists:
        suffix = suffix + 1
    Loop

    Sheets("Interface").Select

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

This works when Params2 exists to produce Params3, but if both Params2 and Params3 exist, it throws the error

> "That name is already taken.  Try a different one."

I don't get why it is able to produce Params3 when Params2 exists, but it can't produce Params4 when both Params2 and Params3 exist.

That is, why is the error not being handled the second time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to clear the error to trigger another one I think. Try to add a `On Error Goto 0` after `suffix = suffix + 1`. This might help too [VBA Error Handling – A Complete Guide](https://excelmacromastery.com/vba-error-handling)

Also note that this loop will run forever if the active sheet cannot be renamed. This might happen eg if `ParamsToBeCloned` contains not allowed characters or if it is longer than 32 characters (Excel's limit for sheet names). So you might want to change it into a `For` loop that has a maximum of eg 1000.

```
For suffix = 2 To 1000
    On Error Resume Next
    ActiveSheet.Name = ParamsToBeCloned & suffix
    If Err.Number = 0 Then 'no error so successfully renamed
        On Error GoTo 0
        Exit For
    End If
    On Error GoTo 0
    If suffix = 1000 Then MsgBox "Maximum reached could not rename sheet"
Next suffix
```

Comment: Thanks Peh.  I did think about a for loop like you have done here, but thought the other was more elegant.  But I do take your point, so I will go the for loop option.  Cheers

Comment: BTW.  On Error GoTo 0 didn't work, but On Error GoTo -1.  Posted here in case this helps someone else.  Thanks again for the help.  Cheers

Comment: @brb Strange actually both should work. If you use `On Error GoTo -1` make sure you have a `On Error GoTo 0` right after your loop. Or it will jump back into the loop if there is an exception behind your loop.

Comment: Hrmm....  let me try again then.  I didn't copy all of the error handling as I got the following to work.  So, maybe my advice was bad...  If so, sorry!!
For suffix = 2 To 100
        On Error GoTo sheetExists
        ActiveSheet.Name = ParamsToBeCloned & suffix
        Exit For
sheetExists:
        On Error GoTo -1
    Next suffix

Answer (score 2):

Just an alternative to using `On Error`:

```
For x = 2 To 1000
    If Application.Evaluate("ISREF(" & ParamsToBeCloned & x & "!A1)") = False Then
        ActiveSheet.Name = ParamsToBeCloned & x
        Exit For
    End If
Next x
```

To check if a worksheet exists we can try to see if `ISREF` returns a `TRUE` or `FALSE`. On `FALSE`, you can name your worksheet.

---

As per @Peh his comment, you might need a way to check if `ParamsToBeCloned` & `x` is a [valid](http://codevba.com/excel/valid_sheet_name.htm#.XXnyEv7grmE) worksheet name first.

Comment: Just a note: While this checks if a sheet exists, it does not check if `ParamsToBeCloned & x` is a valid name or invalid because of length or characters. So it still might need a proper error handling since the name is retrieved form a cell (user input you cannot trust).

Comment: @Pᴇʜ, indeed it would depend on the validation of the `ParamsToBeCloned` variable.

Comment: Yes, that's right. But error handling would probably be easier to realize than validating if a string is a valid name for a sheet :) Actually I cannot imagine an easier way.

Comment: You probably right, however I'll always start to look to circumvent the need for `on error` :). I'll keep the answer up just in case people find it a good use when they working with variables that are valid.

Comment: Of course, I didn't mean to discredit your answer (you got my vote).